# Why does my PHP-script end in a loop?

Tags: php

I wrote a simple PHP scripts which should print 320 random generated ages. These ages should be generated in pairs, and the difference between the ages should be calculated. I wrote the following code, everything but the getDifference function works. If I leave the function out, 320 ages will be generated.

But if I leave the function in it:

> 1) Doesn't work right
>   2) Stays in a long loop
>   3) Sometimes prints out
>   4 ages instead of the 320.

I need some help.

```
    <?php
//Minimum of the age range.
$min = 8;

//Maxium of the age range.
$max = 25;

//Generating the ages
for ($i=0;$i<160;$i++) {
  $age1= random_float($min,$max);
  $firstage= round($age1,1);
  $age2= random_float($min,$max);
  $secondage=round($age2,1);
  $diff = getDifference ($age1, $age2);
  print "Age 1: $firstage  Age 2: $secondage Difference: $diff \n ";

}

//Function to generate a random float number
function random_float ($min,$max) {
   return ($min+lcg_value()*(abs($max-$min)));
}

// Function to calculate the differences between the ages in years and months
function getDifference ($age1, $age2) {
  $difference = abs($age2 - $age1);
  $jaar = 0;
  $newdifference = round($difference,1) * 12;
  for ($newdifference; $newdifference >=12; $newdifference -12) {
    $jaar ++; }
  $month = $newdifference - 12*$jaar;
  $newmonth = floor($month);
  $test = "$jaar years and $newmonth months";
  return $test;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for ($newdifference; $newdifference >=12; $newdifference -12) {
    $jaar ++;
}
```

Two things:

First, you don't need that first loop condition statement.  The variable already exists, there's nothing to declare:

```
for (; $newdifference >=12; $newdifference -12) {
    $jaar ++;
}
```

Second, you never modify `$newdifference` within the loop.  Basically, that third loop condition statement (`$newdifference -12`) doesn't actually *do* anything.  It subtracts 12, but doesn't do anything with the result of that subtraction.  So if the loop begins (because the condition is `true`), then it will *never* end (because the condition will always be `true`).  Perhaps you meant to modify the value in that last loop condition statement?:

```
for (; $newdifference >=12; $newdifference -= 12) {
    $jaar ++;
}
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks for your answer. It's good to know that you don't have to declare the first loop condition statement if it already exists. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jesse: Technically you don't have to declare any of them.  You could do this:  `for (;;) {  }`, which would basically be an infinite loop.  Similar to `while (true) {  }`.  You'd just need to manually break from the loop when needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's stuck in a loop because you're not incrementing your `$i` inside your for loop:

Replace:

```
for ($newdifference; $newdifference >=12; $newdifference -12)
```

By:

```
for ($newdifference; $newdifference >=12; $newdifference -= 12)
```

You need to use the `-=` instead of the `-` because otherwise it's not updating the value of `$newdifference`, it's just returning the result of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing $newdifference at all. Your for loop should be

```
for($newdifference; $newdifference >= 12; $newdifference -= 12) {
```

This will decrement `$newdifference` by 12.